# how to wait in background?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, process, background-process

I have two background jobs with job id 1 and 2. I want to do something when job 1 is done, but I don't want to hang.

Currently what I get is `wait 1 && do whatever`, but this command it self blocks current shell. I want to let `wait` itself runs background. I tried `wait 1 & && do whatever`in zsh but it doesn't work. I get an error : `zsh: parse error near '&&'`.

Note: it's import that I want to **wait in background** rather than *wait for some background jobs to be done*.

Comment: Erm, `( wait 1 && do whatever ) &`?

Comment: not work. get error: ``wait: can't manipulate jobs in subshell``

Comment: @Fólkvangr no, they are simply all background tasks. I just want to do something when job 1 finishes.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax error is because both `&` and `&&` are command separators. `&` starts the command in the background and immediately runs the next one, while `&&` runs the first command, waits for it to finish, and runs the second command if the first one succeeded.

To background two things that you want to run asynchronous to a third thing, use this pattern:

```
( first_thing && second_thing ) &
third_thing
```

Optionally `wait $!` *after* `third_thing` to finish the first two before continuing.

`wait 1` waits for PID 1 to finish, which is unlikely to ever happen while your shell is running. You'll want `wait %1`, which waits for [job spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35026498/96588) 1.

Comment: I change 1 to %1, but still get ``zsh: parse error near `&&'``. what should I do?

Comment: I think this can be a comment rather than an answer.  This is not a solution to the question.

Comment: You should try this before you answer. It of course does not work since process id 1 is not your child.

Comment: @schily the pid is not the key point of this question. In practice, I would of course use the actual pid. The key point is how to wait and this answer doesn't talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think `wait` is not the answer. according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613532/9191338) , `tail` is a better solution.
I should use `( tail --pid=WHATEVER -f /dev/null && do whatever ) &`